# Set radio button to checked based on returned JSON from MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

One of my whacky forms need to be populated automatically when I select a value from a . This is all done using $.ajax and PHP and JSON. So far most the the HTML controls get populated without any problem except for one special type of control- the radio button.
I'm trying to set a radio button in my HTML form to checked state in a radio button group, based on what MySQL returned in JSON.

In MySQL I store radio button state value as `0` or `1` integers for yes or no.

The column name for radio button state in the database is `subscribe_status`. The form name of the radio button HTML control is `subscribe-status`(*I'll change that to remove confusion later on*).

What happens at the moment is ... nothing. I'm not sure why.

**jQuery to change radio button state**:

```
// property defined?
if(output[0].subscribe_status !== undefined){
    // none of radio buttons are checked?
    if($('input[name=subscribe-status]').is(':checked') === false) {
        // check one based on returned JSON
        if(output[0].subscribe_status === 0){
            $('input[name=subscribe-status]').filter('[value=0]').prop('checked', true);
        }else if(output[0].subscribe_status === 1){
            $('input[name=subscribe-status]').filter('[value=1]').prop('checked', true);
        }
    }
}else{
    console.log("Subscribe status property is undefined");
}
```

I perform these inside `success` of `$.ajax` call and it works for other HTML controls like inputs of type `<text>`, `<textarea>` and `<select>`, but not radio buttons. MySQL results are stored into `output` variable as `Object`.

**HTML form:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="subscribe-status" class="sr-only">Subscribed?:</label>
    <label for="subscribe-status">Subscribed?:</label>
    <div class="radio-inline">
        <label for="subscribe-status"><input type="radio" name="subscribe-status" value="1" />Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-inline">
        <label for="subscribe-status"><input type="radio" name="subscribe-status" value="0">No</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Note: I use Bootstrap.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need of `if...else`:

```
$('input[name="subscribe-status"][value="' + output[0].subscribe_status + '"]').prop('checked', true);
```

This will select the `input` element with `name` attribute as `subscribe-status` and having `value` as `output[0].subscribe_status` value.

Make sure your `output` variable if **JSON** and it contains `subscribe_status`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error here

```
$("input[name=subscribe-status]')
```

you start with a double quote and end with a single.